# html Buttons with automatic height and width next to each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, what I am planning to do, is have 4 buttons, which can trigger an action.
However, these are very short in height and don't seem to move around easily. I do have the code for the actions they are supposed to do, but this question is purely about the lay-out.

Two of these buttons should be 35% of the max height and be on the left and right of the screen.
The other 2 should be half the height, and on top of each other, in the middle of the screen.

I think that this should be possible using classes, but I don't know how exactly.
Would appreciate some help.

[Sketch of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOp92.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. It is not perfect by any means but should get ya going at least.

HTML

```
  <div class='container'>
  <button class='side'>L</button>
  <button class='mid'>T</button>
  <button class='mid'>B</button>
  <button class='side'>R</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.side {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.mid{
    height:50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/de6wygtp/39/